# Taking the limit on the lower limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits, area

I have this expression but I'm not sure how to read it:

$$\lim_{a\to 0} \int_{a}^{1} f(x) \,dx$$

Here $f$ is defined over $(0,1]$.

I'll appreciate any guidence

Comment: Integral is function of $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about the limit in two stages:

1. Define the function $g(a) := \int_a^1 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$. Notice that this is a function of $a$, and $a$ alone. Even though you see the variable $x$ in this expression, you're also integrating with respect to $x$. Here, $x$ is playing the role of a dummy variable. We could have written $g(a) := \int_a^1 f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$. This is completely the same.
2. Then
   $$ 
   \lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^1 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{a\to 0} g(a).
   $$